# Stop mis[behavior]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[behavior](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/behavior) is a meta tag that does not appear to add value.  A few of the 8 questions with this tag could benefit from the addition of an existing specific tag (unrelated to "behavior").  Recommend deleting it.

Answer (score 2):

### Done

Tag removed from all questions. Again, obvious meta tag is obvious.